# CANAN Printer 2520 Drivers and Configuration

Tags: printing

I am using CANAN Printer 2520 in my shop.
I want to give print from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I want to know how to install driver and configure printer on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I tried instructions as per below link but getting error.

[http://ubuntuportal.com/2011/12/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-for-linux-ubuntu.html][1]

```
zohaib@mail:~$ sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-ip2600series
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cnijfilter-ip2600series
```

Any idea?

Best Regards,
Shahab

Answer (score 0):

go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100550201.html for the Canon driver for your MG2500 series device. Click to download and select to SAVE what will be cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz

1) open a terminal
2) copy each command below; line by line; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste

1) open the terminal by pressing 3 keys: control and alt and t
2) paste by right-clicking at the text prompt in the terminal; select PASTE from the menu that appears

commands are:

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb
./install.sh
```

and that final command will run the install script; it will ask you questions so watch it; let us know how it goes

Comment: Hi,

I want to know how to add printer to network. I have turn on printer and connect to my laptop. It gives below message

Connect the printer, and then turn on the power.
To use the printer on the network, connect the printer to the network.
When the printer is ready, press the Enter key.
> 
Searching for printers...
Select the printer.
If the printer you want to use is not listed, select Update [0] to search again.
To cancel the process, enter [Q].
Could not detect the target printer.

Comment: try this https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/pixma_printer_wireless_connection_setup/pixma_mg2950_wireless_connection_setup/ it is for the MG2900 series but read the first "WPS Connection Method"  ... ask a friend who might know about this stuff; you press the WPS button on the router; you press the WPS button on the printer; and the two get formally introduced to each other and become friends